# Send push notification using Java Springboot server and Expo React native client

Tags: java, spring-boot, react-native, push-notification, expo

My serser uses Java with SpringBoot and my client is an expo react native app which uses typescript.
I am really blocked by this feature: **I want to sens push notifications**. I tried a lot of methods, but I didn't succeed.

On the client side I am using the method described in expo documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/.
When I use their tool to send test notifications(https://expo.dev/notifications), I receive them on my device.

I didn't manage to send notifications from my client app. I tried all I found on the Inthernet. When I used FirebaseMessagingService  and I used the server key from the firebase project as token, I received the SENDER_ID_MISMATCH error.

```
@Service
public class FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;

    public FirebaseMessagingService(FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging) {
        this.firebaseMessaging = firebaseMessaging;
    }


    public String sendNotification(Note note, String topic) throws FirebaseMessagingException {

        Notification notification = Notification
                .builder()
                .setTitle(note.getSubject())
                .setBody(note.getContent())
                .setImage(note.getImage())
                .build();

        Message message = Message
                .builder()
                .setNotification(notification)
                .putAllData(note.getData())
                .setToken(topic)
                .build();

        return firebaseMessaging.send(message);
    }
}
```

I also found the **expo-server-sdk-java** but I couldn't manage to integrate it.

Any heeeeelp, pleaseeee?

Comment: just use google fcm API to send the push notification, no need of SDK for that https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: I tried right now, but I got {
  "multicast_id": 6889325515579001000,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "MismatchSenderId"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it's the best practice but it works fine for me.

My pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.jav</groupId>
        <artifactId>expo-server-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then in the java class

```
private static void sendPushNotification(String token, String titulo, String mensaje, Map<String, Object> data) throws PushClientException {
    if (!PushClient.isExponentPushToken(token)) throw new Error("Token:" + token + " is not a valid token.");

    ExpoPushMessage expoPushMessage = new ExpoPushMessage();
    expoPushMessage.getTo().add(token);
    expoPushMessage.setTitle(titulo);
    expoPushMessage.setBody(mensaje);
    expoPushMessage.setData(data);

    List<ExpoPushMessage> expoPushMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    expoPushMessages.add(expoPushMessage);

    PushClient client = new PushClient();
    List<List<ExpoPushMessage>> chunks = client.chunkPushNotifications(expoPushMessages);

    List<CompletableFuture<List<ExpoPushTicket>>> messageRepliesFutures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<ExpoPushMessage> chunk : chunks) {
        messageRepliesFutures.add(client.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk));
    }

    // Wait for each completable future to finish
    List<ExpoPushTicket> allTickets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CompletableFuture<List<ExpoPushTicket>> messageReplyFuture : messageRepliesFutures) {
        try {
            allTickets.addAll(messageReplyFuture.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    List<ExpoPushMessageTicketPair<ExpoPushMessage>> zippedMessagesTickets = client.zipMessagesTickets(expoPushMessages, allTickets);

    List<ExpoPushMessageTicketPair<ExpoPushMessage>> okTicketMessages = client.filterAllSuccessfulMessages(zippedMessagesTickets);
    String okTicketMessagesString = okTicketMessages.stream().map(p -> "Title: " + p.message.getTitle() + ", Id:" + p.ticket.getId()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    LOGGER.info("Recieved OK ticket for " + okTicketMessages.size() + " messages: " + okTicketMessagesString);

    List<ExpoPushMessageTicketPair<ExpoPushMessage>> errorTicketMessages = client.filterAllMessagesWithError(zippedMessagesTickets);
    String errorTicketMessagesString = errorTicketMessages.stream().map(p -> "Title: " + p.message.getTitle() + ", Error: " + p.ticket.getDetails().getError()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    LOGGER.error("Recieved ERROR ticket for " + errorTicketMessages.size() + " messages: " + errorTicketMessagesString);

    /**
     // Countdown 30s
     int wait = 30;
     for (int i = wait; i >= 0; i--) {
     System.out.print("Waiting for " + wait + " seconds. " + i + "s\r");
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
     System.out.println("Fetching reciepts...");

     List<String> ticketIds = (client.getTicketIdsFromPairs(okTicketMessages));
     CompletableFuture<List<ExpoPushReceipt>> receiptFutures = client.getPushNotificationReceiptsAsync(ticketIds);

     List<ExpoPushReceipt> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
     try {
     receipts = receiptFutures.get();
     } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

     System.out.println("Recieved " + receipts.size() + " receipts:");

     for (ExpoPushReceipt reciept : receipts) {
     System.out.println("Receipt for id: " + reciept.getId() + " had status: " + reciept.getStatus());
     }
     */
}
```

In the App.js from react native project with EXPO 44 i take expo token in this way

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
  }

  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }

  return token;
}
```

effect from App.js

```
   useEffect(() => {
    initFirebaseApp();
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(async (token) => {
      //store in some place token
    });
    // This listener is fired whenever a notification is received while the app is foregrounded
    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(handleNotification);

    // This listener is fired whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)
    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
        handleNotificationResponse
      );

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
```

notification handlers in App.js

```
  const handleNotification = (response) => {
    // console.log(response);
  };

  const handleNotificationResponse = (response) => {
    // console.log(response)
  };
```

I hope this helps you

Docs

[Expo SDK documentation](https://github.com/jav/expo-server-sdk-java)

[Expo docs reference](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/)